# Get embed info from Youtube embedcode with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, xhtml

I have a YouTube video (with direct Youtube embed code) embedded on my webpage. Now I want to "extract" the src url with JavaScript (maybe with jQuery or Prototype). Because there is no ID or name, I've put a specific div arround to 'access' it.

This is the embedded code:

```
<div id="youtubeVid">
 <object width="468" height="375">
   <param value="http://www.youtube.com/v/GY3qhaJNkLw?fs=1&amp;hl=nl_NL" name="movie">
   <param value="true" name="allowFullScreen">
   <param value="always" name="allowscriptaccess">
   <embed width="468" height="375" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="http://www.youtube.com/v/GY3qhaJNkLw?fs=1&amp;hl=nl_NL">
 </object>
</div>
```

I'm trying to make a JavaScript that will return: **http://www.youtube.com/v/GY3qhaJNkLw?fs=1&hl=nl_NL**

I've tryed allot of things but I can't return the source...
Something like this?

```
var tmp = document.getElementById("youtubeVid").firstChild;
```

But how can I access the source of the embed?

Comment: This question is not relevant to embedded programming - the tag wiki explicitly says that the embedded tag does NOT apply to components embedded on a web page, see stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/embedded. The EMBED tag may be more relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it with this snippet of code:

```
document.getElementById("youtubeVid").getElementsByTagName('embed')[0].src
```